# Trouble running weston in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, wayland

I try to run weston in a minimal debian (without X) in virtualbox.

After installing a minimal debian 9, i install weston and the wayland protocols

```
$ apt install weston wayland-protocols
```

I tried starting weston with weston-launch:

```
$ weston-launch
[...]
[16:40:46.757] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-libweston-1/drm-backend.so'
[16:40:46.762] Initializing drm backend.
[16:40:46.764] logind: session control granted
[16:40:46.764] no drm device found
[16:40:46.764] fatal: failed to create compositor backend
```

So I made a `.config/weston.ini` like so:

```
[core]
backend=wayland-backend.so
```

But, to my dismay, this gives

```
$ weston-launch
[...]
[16:41:46.757] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-libweston-1/wayland-backend.so'
[16:41:46.762] Initializing drm backend.
[16:41:46.764] failed to create display: No such file or directory
[16:41:46.764] fatal: failed to create compositor backend
```

Does this have to do with me running weston in a virtual machine? Is there any backend (apart from headless) that is known to work inside a virtual machine? Is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I assume there is a graphics driver missing, although I'd assume its in the dependencies. Stay with drm backend, `wayland-backend.so` is for running weston in an already running wayland environment. You could try to install `libdrm-intel1` or the virtualbox guest additions. You need drivers for your virtual gpu. Is `libdrm2` installed? It is a dependency of `weston`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that VirtualBox Video driver doesn't support Wayland.

See this bug: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13471

Comment: Vitualbox now supports Wayland. The bug has been fixed. I'm running weston on Virtualbox 7 without issue.